# How to remove horizontal lines in code editor in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

How to remove this horizontal lines in code editor in Android Studio? I guess this feature hide in Setting - Editor. But I can't find it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the horizontal line from this section:

Settings > Editor > Appearance > Disable "Show method separators" section

[image: Screenshot]